# В чём тут ошибка?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Изучаю фреймворк Ruby on Rails по книге Майкла Хартла "Ruby on Rails для начинающих". И столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Воссоздал код 1 в 1 как в книге, а именно

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def hello
    render text: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

И при открытии страницы получаю такую ошибку
[image: Ошибка при запуске]

Так как вот только только начинаю знакомиться с этим камнем, не могу понять что к чему и почему.

P.S. Гуглил, но все ответы что там были, мне были непонятны.

P.S.S. Не ругайте сильно если я задал глупый вопрос я ведь чайник.

Comment: а роут вы создавали или еще что? что там в книге?

Comment: root 'application#hello'

Comment: Это добавлено в routes.rb

Comment: и еще обратите внимание, для какой версии Rails книга, подход в разных версиях может отличаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка означает: "Нет шаблона"

> Для каждого контроллера имеется связанная директория в директории app/views, содержащая файлы шаблонов, которые формируют вьюхи, связанные с этим контроллером. Эти файлы используются для отображения вьюхи, являющейся результатом каждого экшна контроллера.

создайте шаблон, например `app/views/application/hello.html.erb`

Для Rails 5

```
# заменить text: на plain:
render plain: 'hello world'
```

создать шаблон/вид `app/views/application/hello.txt.erb` и добавить туда

```
<%= yield %>
```

рекомендую вам

- [документация RusRails](http://rusrails.ru/)
- [О видах, ActionView](http://rusrails.ru/action-view-overview)